# Safari: divs w/ overflow: visible + z-index: 9999, but still hidden behind another div?

Tags: css, overflow, z-index

I have a `<div>` that shows on `:hover` of another div. In IE & Firefox, the entire `<div>` shows when hovered, but in Safari, part of the hovered div is hidden behind an adjacent div. I have `overflow: visible` set on the hovered div, but the problem persists.

Open this fiddle in both Firefox and Safari and you'll see the issue in Safari.

http://jsfiddle.net/emturano/TRGm9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` will not have an effect on an element if its position is set to `static` ([as it is by default](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)). Set `position:relative` on the container and then `position:relative;` on the items inside to make sure that the hovered element is frontmost. You'll need to make positioning tweaks to make sure everything lines up correctly.

Comment: If you change `.tab-link` & `.tab-link-hover` in the fiddle to both `position:relative;`, same situation in Safari occurs (`.tab-link-hover` is in front of its parent div, but behind the adjacent div).

Comment: It might have something to do with your `translateZ` rule; commenting that out works OK. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TRGm9/4/